# Crash in Facebook ComposerActivity.java within ICS and Jelly Bean

Tags: android, facebook

Iam getting null pointer exception from the ICS and Jelly Bean devices while using the facebook from the below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String mimeType = image.getMimeType();
intent.setType(mimeType);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image.fullSizeImageUri());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

and the crash log is

> 11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 11-03 17:16:10.899:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ComposerActivity.b(ComposerActivity.java:722)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   com.facebook.katana.activity.composer.ComposerActivity.onUserInteraction(ComposerActivity.java:825)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performUserLeaving(Activity.java:4672) 11-03
>   17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnUserLeaving(Instrumentation.java:1209)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performUserLeavingActivity(ActivityThread.java:2670)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2650)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:128) 11-03
>   17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1168)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 11-03
>   17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-03 17:16:10.899:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514) 11-03
>   17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-03
>   17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-03 17:16:10.899:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   11-03 17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760) 11-03
>   17:16:10.899: E/AndroidRuntime(26187):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please guide me how is there any way to fix this issue or let me know when are you going to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This bug report sounds similar to your situation in regards to the Facebook app accepting other mime types such as image or video.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/384045761672099

I'm working on trying to get confirmation as to whether our app supports other mimetypes such as image or video, although my best guess is that we don't and only support plaintext.

You should subscribe to the bug report to stay up to date for the latest news.